# How to fix point and spotlight in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Using unity 5.5.1 and facing an issue in the project i am working on.Suddenly the point light and spotlight stop working in the game view as well as in the scene view,and gives a warning under the Bounce intensity **current real time indirect bounce light shading for spot and point lights is not supported**.

Comment: Try dragging the Bounce Intensity sliders to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Dragging the Bounce Intensity sliders to 0 should remove this warning, there might be more reason why it does this but this solution seem to work most of the time. For the reason why it does this they explain it [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/960399/shadows-in-editor-but-not-in-build.html):

> Point Lights set to Realtime or Mixed with a Bounce Intensity greater than 0 will break your lighting, but lighting will actually work in the editor.

Comment: Changed the value to 0 Still have no light in the project

Answer (score 0):

For Unity 3d 2019.3.0a5, HD Render Pipline

1) Select your gameObject "Point Light" 
2) In window "Inspector": Light>Shadows>Shadow Map>Enable 
Toggle to true.